# What's the difference between wlan.sa, wlan.ra, wlan.ta and wlan.da?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, mac-address

Tshark/wireshark (CLI) has several fields to display for WLAN, including these four (+ description from manual):

- `wlan.sa`: Source address
- `wlan.ra`: Receiver address
- `wlan.ta`: Transmitter address
- `wlan.da`: Destination address

The descriptions from the manual don't make a lot of sense to me. I'd think there would be -just like an ethernet frame- just a source MAC address and a destination MAC address. After capturing some packets and examining them, apparently it sometimes happens not all these fields are used.

Could anyone give me a more clear explanation of the difference between those four addresses? Also, what would be the best equivalent of `eth.src` and `eth.dst` (of ethernet frames)? Which field represents the wireless client's MAC address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After experimenting a bit more on the matter, I've noticed the following.

I was capturing/analyzing with tshark 1.7.x (from my distro repository). `wlan.ra` and `wlan.ta` were indeed rarely set. After manually upgrading to tshark 1.10.x, `wlan.ra` and `wlan.ta` suddenly "started behaving normally".
Although the [display filter reference page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/w/wlan.html) claims `wlan.ra` and `wlan.ta` have been available since version 1.0.0, apparently they didn't work correctly.

I thought I'd share it, since someone else might find it useful.

Answer (score 7):

> The descriptions from the manual don't make a lot of sense to me. I'd think there would be -just like an ethernet frame- just a source MAC address and a destination MAC address.

Sorry, that's not how IEEE Std 802.11 works.  It's not a simple network technology in which hosts always send packets directly to another host; many 802.11 networks involve an access point that forwards packets between machines on the network.

If, for example, a host with the MAC address 00:02:04:06:08:0a sends a packet to another host with the MAC address 0a:08:06:04:02:00, and they're both on a network using an access point with the MAC address 10:12:14:16:18:1a, the source address, `wlan.sa`, is 00:02:04:06:08:0a, the destination address, `wlan.da`, is 0a:08:06:04:02:00, and the receiver address, `wlan.ra`, is 10:12:14:16:18:1a, as the packet will go to the access point.

When the access point transmits that packet to the destination host, for that packet the source address, `wlan.sa`, is again 00:02:04:06:08:0a, the destination address, `wlan.da`, is again 0a:08:06:04:02:00, and the transmitter address, `wlan.ta`, is 10:12:14:16:18:1a, as the packet is coming from the access point.

In a more complicated network with multiple access points (an "extended service set"), access points may forward packets to each other, in which case all four addresses could be set, with `wlan.ta` being the MAC address of the sending access point and `wlan.ra` being the MAC address of the receiving access point.

So:

> Also, what would be the best equivalent of `eth.src` and `eth.dst` (of ethernet frames)?

`wlan.sa` and `wlan.da`.

> Which field represents the wireless client's MAC address?

`wlan.sa`.

If you search for "802.11 tutorial" on the Web, some of the tutorials it shows might be useful.

If you're willing to "take a drink from the firehose", there's always [the 802.11 standards themselves](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/802/802.11.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this makes it a lot clearer. But can you also tell me why `wlan.sa` and `wlan.da` sometimes is empty? `wlan.da` is empty most of the times apparently.

Comment: Control frames aren't "bridged" through the access point, and they have only a transmitter address (`wlan.ta`) and a receiver address (`wlan.ra`), they don't have a source or destination address (`wlan.sa` or `wlan.da`).  As for `wlan.da` being empty most of the time, I just did a monitor-mode capture on our network, and neither `wlan.sa` nor `wlan.da` are empty on most of the packets.  (Do *NOT* assume that the Source and Destination columns are `wlan.sa` and `wlan.da`, respectively - they aren't!)

Answer (score 3):

From https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/52391/80211-frames-starter-guide-learn-wireless-sniffer-traces:

"Destination Address (DA) : Final recipient of the frame
Source Address (SA) : Original source of the frame
Receiver Address (RA) : Immediate receiver of the frame
Transmitter Address (TA) : Immediate sender of the frame"

Their values are interpreted in combination with values of To DS, From DS (To / From - distribution system):

**To DS=0, From DS=0**

A frame sent between two stations not being APs in a BSS  or IBSS. It is also the case for all management and control frames (directly sent to the AP and not the DS)


**To DS=0, From DS=1**

A frame sent by a station for an AP (destined to the DS)


**To DS=1, From DS=0**

A frame exiting the DS for a station.


**To DS=1,From DS=1**

Only frame using all four addresses fields. Seen in  Wireless DS (mesh, repeater, …) where an AP sends a frame to another AP, it  is exiting the DS and destined to the DS at the same time in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled on this question and thought [my own answer from a similar question on NE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/25102/33) could be helpful to users here as well.

---

The distinction to understand is that while an 802.11 device is transmitting to a receiving device, either one (or both) of these devices may not be the actual source or destination of the L2 traffic. So this can create situations where you need four different distinct addresses:

- Transmitter Address (TA)
- Receiver Address (RA)
- Source Address (SA)
- Destination Address (DA)

The BSSID of the wireless network may be the TA or RA, but it can also may be an identifier to associate traffic to a BSS. Unless the access point (AP) uses the same MAC address for the management interface and the BSSID, you generally won't have any traffic where the BSSID is either the SA or DA.

The use the address fields in an 802.11 header is tied to the To/From DS (distribution system) flags. Depending on how the To/From DS flags are set, this determines which of the four fields are required and what information each provides.

Here are a couple quick summary tables that I took from an [IEEE document](http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/802_architecture_group/802-11/4-address-format.doc):

[image]

[image]

Let me add a couple of images to provide examples taken from [802.11 Wireless Networks: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100520.do) by O'Reilly Press:

[image]

[image]